# How to fix any errors

Tags: c++

error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘structTicket’ and ‘int’)
    WriteTicket(file,masstickets[i]);

```
   bool WriteTickets(structTicket & masstickets, int count, const string filepath)
    {
        bool written = false;
        ofstream file(filepath);
        if(file)
        {
            file << count << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                WriteTicket(file, masstickets[i]);
            file.close();
            written = true;
        }
        return written;
}
```

and here : 1-2.cpp:136:31: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘structTicket&’ from expression of type ‘structTicket*’
   bool written = WriteTickets(masstickets ,count ,FilePath);

```
int main()
{
    structTicket * masstickets;
    int count;
    bool read= ReadTickets(masstickets, count, FilePath);
    if(read)
    {
        cout<< "Файл" << FilePath<< "прочитан."<<endl;
        cout<< "-----------------------------------------------" <<endl; 
        WriteTicketsToTable(masstickets, count);
        bool written = WriteTickets(masstickets ,count ,FilePath);
        if(written)
            cout<< "Файл" << FilePath << "записан." <<endl;
        else
            cout<< "Файл" << FilePath << "Не записан. "<<endl;
        cout<< "-----------------------------------------------" <<endl;
```

Comment: Did you overload [] in structTicket?

Comment: @Dan1505 The parameter type and the type of the argument are mismatching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second error is arising, because your passing wrong argument types.
This function:

```
bool WriteTickets(structTicket & masstickets, int count, const string filepath)
```

takes a reference of `structTicket` what you are passing is a pointer:

```
structTicket * masstickets; // pointer to structTicket
bool written = WriteTickets(masstickets ,count ,FilePath);
```

To call by pass-by-reference you would have to call it like that:

```
bool written = WriteTickets(*masstickets ,count ,FilePath);
```

For the first error to solve, you have to overload the `[]-operator` like @nicomp suggested, but maybe we can see the WriteTicket function to see what argument is needed?

Comment: This answer tells nothing about the error mentioned in the question: "_error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘structTicket’ and ‘int’)_"

Comment: Except `masstickets` has not been initialized yet, so this is UB.

Comment: @Eljay Technically, we don't know that. The call to `ReadTickets`, and `WriteTicketsToTable` is before the call to `WriteTickets`. And we don't know what those functions do, and whether they assign a value to `masstickets`.

Comment: @Eljay I would think that masstickets get initialized in readTickets

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I first referred only to the second error, then looking into the first.

Comment: I would assume that ReadTikets fill an array of structTicket it could be bool ReadTicket(structTicket * & massTicket, int& count), so the WriteTickets function shall be WriteTickets(structTicket *mass Tickets, int count).
On an unrelated note, this would be better C++ if the OP used std::vector or std::list of structTicket (and find a better name such as Ticket)

Comment: @Nico238 you are indeed right. But we don't really know, what the OP is trying to achieve and what limitations he has. Not everyone is able to use the standard container and such (e.g. embedded development)

Comment: Agreed, depends what `ReadTickets` does.  Probably could use a [mcve] since there are many unknowns with the OP's snippet.

Comment: here is WriteTicket func, you ask about it: void WriteTicket(ostream & file, const structTicket  & perticket)
{
 file
  <<perticket.train<<endl
  <<perticket.station1<<endl
  <<perticket.station2<<endl
  <<perticket.dep_day<<endl
  <<perticket.dep_time<<endl
  <<perticket.coach<<endl
  <<perticket.seat<<endl
  <<perticket.price<<endl;
}

Comment: @Dan1505 how is your struct structTicket built? Why do you use structs instead of classes?